# cannot deserialize the current json object Message shows when I try to read the below Json data into Objects

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

Having trouble when trying to deserialize the following JSON content into objects, especially the content in **`eInv` part**

```json
{
    "requestType": "SaveDocuments",
    "status": "P",
    "version": "v0.1",
    "validationReport": null,
    "dataReport": [
        {
            "locationGstin": "DSAJJ0AAGCR31",
            "locationName": "ABC MARKET",
            "documentNumber": "2947",
            "documentDate": "23-10-2020",
            "billFromGstin": "DDLDF07AAGCL",
            "supplyType": "S",
            "documentType": "LST",
            "portCode": null,
            "custom1": null,
            "custom2": null,
            "custom3": null,
            "custom4": null,
            "custom5": null,
            "custom6": null,
            "custom7": null,
            "custom8": null,
            "custom9": null,
            "custom10": null,
            "eInv": {
                "ackNumber": "1721101",
                "ackDate": "01-02-2021 18:54:00",
                "irn": "2d9a39998157b984276e6f1d3b8f74597d7850f0b7ba88c251556e4436b2bb0e",
                "signedInvoice": "CJWeJKYynrWOw2k-GLO-vDipfOohtqW1xh5bg",
                "signedQRCode": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQe5VoYONjADbEYzGABzAz8cCyLXDfNENkZ_TXHw",
                "qrCode": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAG0AAABtCAYAAACrXCIc",
                "qrCodeData": "{\"SellerGstin\":\"abc\",\"BuyerGstin\":\"def\",\"DocNo\":\"234\",\"DocTyp\":\"ghi\",\"DocDt\":\"23/10/2020\",\"TotInvVal\":4005.00,\"ItemCnt\":4,\"MainHsnCode\":\"abc\",\"Irn\":\"321absd432\",\"IrnDt\":\"2021-02-01 18:54:00\"}",
                "errors": null
            },
            "propertyErrors": null
        }
    ],
    "referenceId": "abcdesf="
}
```

Comment: Hi Paapu, thank you for your question. A couple of ways you could improve your question: we may be able to infer it from your tags (it looks like C#), it is still helpful to list what technology you are using; and please provide the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Find yourself a JSON aware editor, such as Visual Studio Code, or Google for any online JSON viewer and get into the habit of using these tools to check your JSON.

for example, https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=local.taxoru&right=local.hucize gives this error with your JSON:

```
Parse error on line 3:
...", "qrCodeData": "{"SellerGstin":"abc","
-----------------------^
```

remove the first `"`
after `"qrCodeData":` and you should be valid.